# Wrong ViewController navigation in iOS app writtern in Objective c Login Forgot password segue issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, segue

I am working on old iOS Objective c app. I have login code working. Login button and logic all created in .m file. I am trying to add forgot password Link to separate view controller with segue defined in the storyboard. that's working. But Now when I click the login button it passes login function but at the end open up forgot password view controller. I am not pretty familiar with segue.

Can anyone help me what I am getting wrong? It will be a great help.
Forgot password segue is directly connected in the storyboard. I don't have preparesegue method implemented

```
  //login button added
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.title = @"Log In";
    logInButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [self.logInButton setFrame:CGRectMake(86, 324, 142, 37)];
    [self.view addSubview:logInButton];
    [logInButton setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logInButton setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [logInButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15]];
    [logInButton setTitle:@"Log In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logInButtonDePressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    }

//login button clicked
(void)logInButtonPressed{
    [self.userNameTf resignFirstResponder];
    [self.passwordTf resignFirstResponder];
    [self logIn];
}

//login code
(BOOL)logIn{
        [self logInParser:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",
                           [userNameTf text],[passwordTf text]]];
        return TRUE;
}

-(void)logInParser:(NSString*)httpBodyString{

    NSURL *URL =[NSURL URLWithString:[apiURL stringByAppendingString:@"apiURL"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[httpBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection){
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls post some code, especially `prepareForSegue:` method (if it is there), login and forgot password actions from your view controller

Comment: @DennisPashkov can you suggest something now?

Comment: It looks like your login button target doesn't match up to your method: `logInButtonDePressed` compared to `(void)logInButtonPressed` also you're missing a dash at the beginning of that method and the login method.

Comment: There is no code which switch view controllers.

Comment: If its connected in storyboard you need to change connection to right storyboard